# xargs nano leads to Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM while xargs less is OK

Tags: xargs, nano, sigterm, sighup

Scenario:

```
$ cat t0.txt
t1.txt

$ cat t1.txt
xxx

$ sed -n 1p t0.txt | xargs less
# OK

$ sed -n 1p t0.txt | xargs nano
Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM

dvl-linux64 $ nano --version
 GNU nano, version 2.5.3
```

How to open file in `nano`? If not `xargs`, then what?

UPD. On Cywgin:

```
$ sed -n 1p t0.txt | xargs less
# OK

$ sed -n 1p t0.txt | xargs nano
Too many errors from stdin

$ sed -n 1p t0.txt | nano
Too many errors from stdin

Buffer written to nano.save

$ nano --version
 GNU nano, version 4.9
```

Comment: If you're using nano 2.2 or later you should be able just to pipe directly to nano. [Check this post](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/TODO)

Comment: See UPD. On Linux the version 2.5.3, on Windows (Cygwin) it is 4.9. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `sed -n 1p t0.txt | xargs --open-tty nano`. Someone take it from here please, as I have no time for an educative answer.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks! Works for xargs 4.9.0. Doesn't work for xargs 4.7.0: `xargs: unrecognized option '--open-tty'`.

Comment: Without `--open-tty`: `sed -n 1p t0.txt | xargs sh -c '</dev/tty exec nano "$@" ' sh` .